# World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, arkit

I made an app that can track hand positions and move the AR object according to the finger position. The main method uses the vision framework. The code functions without any issue, however the instant the hand is detected in the camera, the programs freezes for almost one second before functioning properly.  This is the code where I call the vision framework.

```
    // MARK: - SCNSceneRendererDelegate
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
        updateCoreML()
    }
```

This is the output in the console log. This will always get printed whenever I restart the app.

```
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds]
PID: 4771, TID: 5232327, Thread name: com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer, Queue name: com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x106705f90, QoS: 33
Backtrace:
4   AR_1                                0x00000001029146b4 $s4AR_114ViewControllerC12updateCoreMLyyF + 11688
5   AR_1                                0x0000000102917a0c $s4AR_114ViewControllerC8renderer_14didRenderScene6atTimeySo16SCNSceneRenderer_p_So0J0CSdtF + 72
6   AR_1                                0x0000000102917a74 $s4AR_114ViewControllerC8renderer_14didRenderScene6atTimeySo16SCNSceneRenderer_p_So0J0CSdtFTo + 92
7   SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d578f0 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1505520
8   SceneKit                            0x00000001e0dde3d4 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 2057172
9   SceneKit                            0x00000001e0c56040 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 450624
10  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0c5785c EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 456796
11  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5d010 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1527824
12  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5d87c EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1529980
13  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5de20 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1531424
14  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5e204 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1532420
15  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0e009a0 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 2197920
16  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0cb5958 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 842072
17  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0dc9be0 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1973216
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030a56c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030b5f14 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 176
20  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0dc9b64 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1973092
21  GPUToolsCore                        0x00000001032a4f44 -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
22  QuartzCore                          0x00000001afc8b6fc 8510F139-0824-3686-A9AA-3E198539A021 + 83708
23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001afd64a80 8510F139-0824-3686-A9AA-3E198539A021 + 973440
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac910dd0 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 511440
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac935fe8 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 663528
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac935378 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 660344
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac92f08c 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 635020
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac92e21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
29  Foundation                          0x00000001adbdddf0 7698BF3E-0CF6-31C0-85E9-562714F01276 + 36336
30  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0cb5ea4 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 843428
31  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0cb61bc EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 844220
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001f8467cb0 _pthread_start + 320
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001f8470778 thread_start + 8
2021-03-04 20:42:49.062465+0900 AR_1[4771:5232327] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds]
PID: 4771, TID: 5232327, Thread name: com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer, Queue name: com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x106705f90, QoS: 33
Backtrace:
4   AR_1                                0x00000001029146b4 $s4AR_114ViewControllerC12updateCoreMLyyF + 11688
5   AR_1                                0x0000000102917a0c $s4AR_114ViewControllerC8renderer_14didRenderScene6atTimeySo16SCNSceneRenderer_p_So0J0CSdtF + 72
6   AR_1                                0x0000000102917a74 $s4AR_114ViewControllerC8renderer_14didRenderScene6atTimeySo16SCNSceneRenderer_p_So0J0CSdtFTo + 92
7   SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d578f0 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1505520
8   SceneKit                            0x00000001e0dde3d4 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 2057172
9   SceneKit                            0x00000001e0c56040 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 450624
10  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0c5785c EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 456796
11  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5d010 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1527824
12  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5d87c EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1529980
13  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5de20 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1531424
14  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0d5e204 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1532420

15  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0e009a0 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 2197920
16  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0cb5958 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 842072
17  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0dc9be0 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1973216
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030a56c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001030b5f14 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 176
20  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0dc9b64 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 1973092
21  GPUToolsCore                        0x00000001032a4f44 -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
22  QuartzCore                          0x00000001afc8b6fc 8510F139-0824-3686-A9AA-3E198539A021 + 83708
23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001afd64a80 8510F139-0824-3686-A9AA-3E198539A021 + 973440
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac910dd0 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 511440
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac935fe8 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 663528
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac935378 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 660344
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac92f08c 727F2644-EB4E-3D57-BC2E-E6803BA92366 + 635020
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ac92e21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
29  Foundation                          0x00000001adbdddf0 7698BF3E-0CF6-31C0-85E9-562714F01276 + 36336
30  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0cb5ea4 EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 843428
31  SceneKit                            0x00000001e0cb61bc EC930BC7-1D62-3C34-AE79-B49A41F6198E + 844220
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001f8467cb0 _pthread_start + 320
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001f8470778 thread_start + 8
2021-03-04 20:42:57.812761+0900 AR_1[4771:5233782] [Technique] ARWorldTrackingTechnique <0x10341bc30>: World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [0]
```

I think the timing of the function called is not correct, that is why it says the performance is being affected by resource constraints. I tried to use `updateAtTime` delegate but it does not work. Calling separate thread may also work but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Why does the Main Queue fix works**

You are calling a UIKit function (`view.bounds` in your case) outside of the Main Queue, which is not allowed in Swift.

- **Explanation about **ARC** and `[weak self]`:**

`Weak` refers to automatic reference counting (**ARC**) of the object inside a block.

**Reference counting** - Swift's memory management.
You can read more about it here:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

In this case, we use the `[weak self]` in our **closure capturing list** (See: [Closure Capture List](https://medium.com/fantageek/capture-list-in-swift-c79657b64974#:%7E:text=Closures%20are%20self%2Dcontained%20blocks,lambdas%20in%20other%20programming%20languages.)) to make sure self (in your case **ViewController**) is not strongly retain.

In other words, if your **ViewController** instance is to be released, before the block execution is called, the instance will be released and self will equal to **nil** once the block is called.

Answer (score 1):

According to the log, inside `updateCoreML()`, you are calling something that has to do with UIKit changes.

Can you try wrapping this function in the following matter?

```
// MARK: - SCNSceneRendererDelegate
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
      self?.updateCoreML() 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I am still not totally of sure why this fixed it. What is the meaning of weak self?